# When I edit a plane with an image texture it distorts oddly

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I'm just scaling (pictured) a single plane, with the **left-side edge** but the scale of the texture doesn't scale properly . . **why does this happen?** This is just a single plane with a simple plane UV (smart UV)

[image]

Comment: try applying the transform

Comment: If i apply the scale, the error keeps happening :/

Comment: sorry that has nothing to do with it,  is it generated or uv map

Comment: This is because the plane is actually rendered as two triangles, so the generated UVs are messed up. UV unwrapping again might work however, if you haven't tried it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There is a smiple fix:** add a sub surf modifier and set it to simple. Be sure to increase to subdivisions.

[image]

The issue is that because a face is made of 2 triangles, the uvs are stretched across the triangles and not the mesh.